# MySQL PDO create and populate 1000 small tables in 3 seconds or less?

Tags: mysql, pdo, innodb, query-performance

Is it possible? From a single process?
DB is on SATA disk.
I am using ubuntu 14.04. All tables have 20-60 rows and 6 columns each.
I am using transactions.

The current sequence is:

1. Create table
2. Start transaction
3. Insert #1
4. Insert #2
5. ...
6. Insert #n
7. Commit

Right now I am getting about 3-4 tables/second.

**Conclusion:** When I disabled logging my performance became similar to phpmyadmin. So, as Rick James suggested, I guess there is no way to achieve further improvements without a faster storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a spinning drive, you can get about 100 operations per second.  `CREATE TABLE` might be slower since it involves multiple file operations in the OS.  So, I would expect 1000 `CREATE TABLEs` to take more than 10 seconds.  That's on Ubuntu; longer on Windows.

It is usually poor schema design to make multiple tables that are identical; instead have a single table with an extra column to distinguish the subsets.

`INSERTing` 40K rows--

- 40K single-row `INSERTs` with `autocommit=ON` -- 400 seconds.
- 1000 multi-row `INSERTs` of 20-60 rows each, again `COMMITted` after each statement -- 10 seconds.
- A single `INSERT` with 40K rows (if you don't blow out some other limitation) -- possibly less than 1 second.

Do not use multi-statement queries; it is a potential security problem.  Anyway, it won't help much.

Comment: One of the reasons for me creating 1000 tables is to improve search/update speeds and to allow for concurrency. I've noticed that adminer reloads the whole DB ( 3477 queries on about 1200 tables) in about 144 seconds on the same setup. Thats about 3 times faster. So what am I missing? Are the numbers above from your experience or from another source?

Comment: My experience.  But there are a lot of variables (disk speed, driver, etc, etc), so 3x difference is in the ballpark.  What I described was a single connection to a single table.  Multiple (but not 1000) connections to a single InnoDB table will be faster.  Still, the OS will take time to do 1000 table creations.

Answer (score 1):

For create table  you could perform  a multi statement query  (PDO support this) so in a single query  you can create several table  and t for insert 
you could use bulk insert  preparing a sql insert query with repeated  insert value  and the execute as a single query

The bulk insert is based on

```
INSERT INTO your_table( col1, col2,,,) 
VALUES ( val1_1, val1_2 ,,,), 
       ( vale2_1, val2_2 ,,,), 
       ....
```

Then you can build a PDO query based  on these tecnique and do the fact the execution if for you single statement  and not for each statement as ne number of values you can inset  thousand of value in a query and get the result in a few seconds

> the Use the multiple-row INSERT syntax reduce communication overhead
>   between the client and the server if you need to insert many rows This
>   tip is valid for inserts into any table, not just InnoDB tables.

Comment: I thought transactions would produce the same result as multiple-row INSERT. My limited testing seems to confirm this. I.e. no improvement.

Comment: @gene - transactions won't be any better because there is overhead of setup and teardown of each single-row `INSERT`.